# Calculating equations for image of variety under map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is another qualifying exam practice problem that I'm having trouble with.  I'm asked to compute polynomials which cut out the image of the variety $x^2+y^2-1=0$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$ under the map $\mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$ defined by $(x,y) \mapsto (xy,x^2-y^2)$.  It's clear that one equation that is needed is $(xy^2+(x^2-y^2)^2-1=0$, but I have no idea how to show that more equations are not needed.  Thanks for any help!